# Why can't my integers be transferred to an array?

Tags: c++

I want to make a program that works with integers that were inputted using space and not enter. when you input the integers `12 80 33 99` with space between each one of them, then the code will separate the integers and put them into an array.

I'm using codeblocks, C++

```
int main(){
int A;
int j [10] ={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
cin >> A;
string As;
bool code = true;
int hasil [A][10];
getline(cin,As);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < A ; i++){

        while (code){

            if( cin.get() != '\n'){

            cin >> hasil[i][j[i]];
            j[i]++;

            }else{ code = false;}
    }}
    for (int i = 0 ;i < A ; i++){
        for (int x = 0; x != j[i]; x++){
            cout << hasil[i][x]<< " " ;
        }
        cout << " " << endl;
    }
return 0;}
```

When I input `25 17 70 88`, I expected the output to be `25 17 70 88` too, but the actual output was `5 17 70 88`. Where is my first `2`?

Comment: @Spinkoo it isn't undefined behavior it is ill-formed by the standard. but works on most compiler through extensions.

Comment: When you input 25 17 70 88, A will become 25, but your array j has the size 10. Possible buffer overrun, undefined behavior in case of long input.

Comment: Anytime you get into mathematical error you need to use your debugger to step through your code one line at a time looking at the flow of the execution and the values of the variables at each step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `2` was eaten by the call to `cin.get()` which reads one character which your code then throws it away.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand exactly what you are trying to do but i can see an error in your code which might cause undefined behaviour. `int hasil[A][10]` is a static array which means compiler must know its size at compile time, however A is not a compile time constant. If you don't know the size of your array you should use a pointer instead or even better a std container such as `std::vector`.
To make your code more readable you can also delete the `code` variable and replace your first for loop body with

```
while(cin.get() != '\n)
{
   cin >> .....
   ...
}
```